# How to do text replacement without a keylogger?

Tags: windows, logging, text, automation, keyboard

I am looking to make a text replacement program for windows like the feature on iPhones as a personal-use side project b/c I'm sick of typing out repetitive things. I understand something like AutoHotKey exists, but I wanted to try making something like it for fun.

My initial thought was to use a keylogger to track when it is typed and replace it accordingly. However, I know keylogger can be used maliciously, so I ideally want to avoid using it even if it is for personal use only. I also considered programming macro keys to do text replacement, but it seems limited in how many I can have. Are there any alternatives? According to AutoHotKey, they don't utilize keyloggers and I'm not super well-versed in this area, so would appreciate any advice and direction!